# Linq2Sql -How to write group by query

Tags: linq-to-sql

If I have the following fields in a table called DailyLeaveLedger

- LeaveDate
- LeaveType
- AmountPaid

How do I write a linq2sql group by query to get this result where
it groups by year and Leavetype and gives a column of the count of
leave days and the sum of amount paid?? Sorted in descending order of year.

```
2010    Annual    10  5,000.00

2010    Personal  3    1,500.00

2009    Annual    15   10,000.00

2009 etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Axarydax' result:

```
var result = DailyLeaveLedgers.OrderBy(p=>p.LeaveDate.Year)
                              .GroupBy(p => new { 
                                  Year = p.LeaveDate.Year, 
                                  Type = p.LeaveType 
                              })
                              .Select(g => new { 
                                  Year = g.Key.Year, 
                                  Type = g.Kye.Leave, 
                                  Count = g.Count(),
                                  Sum = g.Sum(x => x.AmmountPaid)
                              });
```

`result` now holds a enumeration of objects from with the requested data.

Answer (score 2):

DailyLeaveLedgers.OrderBy(p=>p.LeaveDate.Year).GroupBy(p => new { p.LeaveDate.Year, p.LeaveType });

Comment: Thanks how do I get the count and sum amount paid?